# Why it doesn't have the module i40evf.ko in ubuntu-18.04-server-cloudimg-amd64.img?

Tags: ubuntu, intel, ubuntu-cloud

I downloaded ubuntu-18.04-server-cloudimg-amd64.img from [1](http://uec-images.ubuntu.com/releases/releases/18.04/release/ubuntu-18.04-server-cloudimg-amd64.img) and create a KVM instance with it. After I assigned a xl710 vf to the instance , I could not find the interface in the instance.

After researching, I found that there is no i40evf.ko in the image, however the driver module is built to module from the kernel config located in /boot/config-4.15.0-20-generic

```
root@ubuntu:~# modinfo i40evf
modinfo: ERROR: Module i40evf not found.

root@ubuntu:~# cat /boot/config-4.15.0-20-generic | grep I40EVF
CONFIG_I40EVF=m
```

Do anyone know why it is?